# empty consolewindow when executing c-programs using scanf-function

Tags: c, scanf

I am really new to c-language. I have the following problem.

If I use scanf()-function the program does not seem to execute properly. I am using Eclipse and the console window is empty. BUT - when I termine the c-program everything is showing up in the console-window.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
  int i;
 char c;
 char s[10];
 float f;

 printf("Enter an integer number:");
 scanf("%d",&i);
 fflush(stdin);
 printf("Enter string:");
 scanf("%s",s);
 fflush(stdin);
 printf("Enter a floating number:");
 scanf("%f",&f);
 fflush(stdin);
 printf("Enter a character:");
 scanf("%c",&c);

 printf("\nYou have entered \n\n");
 printf("integer:%d \ncharacter:%c \nstring:%s \nfloat:%f",i,c,s,f);
 getch();
}
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Try using `c = getchar();` instead of `scanf("%c",&c);` for inputting character. `scanf()` is not nice in scanning single characters.

Comment: Also, What do you mean by terminating the program? if you terminate the program, how come you see console window?

Comment: Is this C or C++? Does your test file end to `.c` or `.cpp`? In your posting you mention "*C-language*", which is **not** the same as C++. So you might like to decide which tag to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stdout`, which `printf()` writes to, is line buffered, so it is only flushed when encountering a `\n`.

So to have your input prompts appear, you need to explictly flush `stdout`:

```
printf("Enter an integer number:");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &i);
```

---

On termination of the program buffers are implicitly flushed, that's why `printf()`ed data lasted appear on the console when the program has ended.

---

However, from the source you post there should be data printed to the console after this line had been execute:

```
printf("\nYou have entered \n\n");
```

As there are `\n`s. So I assume you do not show us the exact code.